# Variance of a function of a normal random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I want to define a new random variable $f$ as a function of a normal random variable $v$:
$$f(v)=\begin{cases}C&\text{if } v\ge C\\ \gamma v &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

where $v\sim N(v_0,\sigma_v)$ and $C$ is constant.

How should I compute the variance of $f$? Can anyone help me?
Thanks, PM

Comment: I don't think this is a valid density function.  How can you have finite probability on the interval from $C$ to infinity?

Comment: @trb456: As $v$ is normally distributed, the variance of $f$ will be finite.

Comment: @user61677: As my comments are suggesting, I think some editing to your question would help clarify what you want.  Instead of your function *f*, which I am likely mistaking for a pdf, do instead mean you want to define a new random variable as a function of an existing normal random variable?  This may seem picky, but I think it would be more clear.

Comment: Twice the post mentions $f$ and twice it should read $f(v)$. (Note furthermore that random variables are most often denoted by capital letters, in which case the random variable of interest would be $f(V)$.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you want to go about this is to express the expected value of $f$ as

$$E[f(V)] = \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_0} \int_{-\infty}^C dv \: v \exp{\left [ - \frac{(v-v_0)^2}{2 \sigma_0^2} \right ]} + \frac{C}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_0} \int_{C}^{\infty} dv \: \exp{\left [ - \frac{(v-v_0)^2}{2 \sigma_0^2} \right ]} $$

where $V$ is the normally distributed random variable.  Also,

$$E[f(V)^2] = \frac{\gamma^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_0} \int_{-\infty}^C dv \: v^2 \exp{\left [ - \frac{(v-v_0)^2}{2 \sigma_0^2} \right ]} + \frac{C^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_0} \int_{C}^{\infty} dv \: \exp{\left [ - \frac{(v-v_0)^2}{2 \sigma_0^2} \right ]} $$

The variance is

$$\mathrm{Var}[f(V)] = E[f(V)^2] - E[f(V)]^2$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you are integrating is not the OP's function, which I again reiterate is not a valid density function as written.

Comment: @trb456: Where did the OP say that $f$ is a density function?  $f$ is not a density function, but rather a function of the random variable $V$.

Comment: @rlgordonna: The new random variable still needs a density function, and what you are integrating is not it. At a minimum, you have the support backwards (constant *above* $C$ as written).  But more seriously, what is the pdf when the normal random variable exceeds $C$?  You seem to want to assume it's normally distributed above $C$, and you are likely be right that this is what the OP meant, but if so then this could be better expressed than currently.

Comment: @trb456: thanks for catching my error.  As for the density function of $f(V)$, I am not assuming anything that the OP hasn't stated.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! f is not a density function, but a function of the random variable v.

Comment: It looks like @trb456 assumed that $f$ automatically meant density fuction, and at first, I admit, I did too.  Perhaps you could spell it out a bit more explicitly, but then again, it is the responsibility of those answering the questions to read the questions carefully.

Comment: @trb456: perhaps you did not catch the $N(v_0,\sigma_0)$, which means that the random variable $V$ (which the OP mistakenly labeled as $v$) is normally distributed with mean $v_0$ and variance $\sigma_0$.  The OP should have also called it $\mathcal{N}(v_0,\sigma_0)$.

Comment: How would the results change if now, v is time varying, assumed to be an ar(1) process, that is,

Comment: v(t)=v0*(1-phi)+phi*v(t-1)+epsilon, with epsilon~N(0,sigmae) and 0<phi<1 and v0>C. Could you help me?

Comment: Why don't you pose another problem and close out this one if my solution helped you?  BY "closing out," I mean accept the solution if it works for you.

Comment: OK, I will do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the results for a [truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).  I assume $\sigma_v$ is a standard deviation rather than a variance.

Let $\beta = \dfrac{C-v_0}{\sigma_v}$, $b=\phi(\beta)$ and $B=\Phi(\beta)$ using the PDF and CDF of a standard normal distribution.  Then the first moment about zero could be something like  $$E[f] = B \gamma \left(  v_0 - \frac{b}{B} \sigma_v \right) +(1-B)C$$

which you can simplify.

You can then work out the second moment in a similar way and thus the variance of $f$, but I will leave that for you. For what it is worth, my attempt at the second moment (before I decided to stop, so unchecked) was

$$ B \gamma^2 \left(\sigma_v \left( 1 - \frac{b \beta}{ B} -\frac{b^2}{B^2} \right) +  \left(v_0 - \frac{b}{B} \sigma_v\right)^2\right) +(1-B)C^2$$ and you just need to subtract the square of the first moment to give the variance.